# Error de resolución de sobrecarga porque ninguna de las funciones 'New' a las que se tiene acceso acepta este número de argumentos

Tags: vb.net, .net, aforge

tengo este trozo de código, el cual me da un error en la declaración de 'cGrabacion'. El error es el del titulo, las librerias que estoy usando son Aforge y emgu.cv . Si alguno sabe el error, y porque puede ser, que me diga. Gracias de antemano. Un saludo

```
 If ret = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        cPathGRabacion = vCarpetaDialog.SelectedPath
        cGrabacion = New VideoWriter(fileName, compressionCode, fps, Width, Height, isColor)



        Dim vArchivoInfo As FileInfo
        For Each vArchivoInfo In cArchivos
            cVideoF = New FileVideoSource(vArchivoInfo.FullName)
            CargarVideo(vArchivoInfo.FullName)
            cGrabacion = New VideoWriter(fileName, compressionCode, fps, Width, Height, isColor)
            'cGrabacion.Open(cPathGRabacion & "\Minuto_" & vArchivoInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("HHmm") & ".flv", CInt(AnchoTxt.Text), CInt(AltoTxt.Text), cVideo.FrameRate, VideoCodec.FLV1, 5242880)
            cGrabacion.Open(cPathGRabacion & "\Minuto_" & vArchivoInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("HHmm") & ".flv", CInt(AnchoTxt.Text), CInt(AltoTxt.Text), cVideo.FrameRate, VideoCodec.FLV1, True)
            cVideoF.Start()
            cVideoF.WaitForStop()
            cGrabacion.Close()

            'CargarVideo(vArchivoInfo.FullName)
            'cGrabacion = New VideoFileWriter
            'cGrabacion.Open(cPathGRabacion & "\Minuto_" & vArchivoInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("HHmm") & ".flv", CInt(AnchoTxt.Text), CInt(AltoTxt.Text), cVideo.FrameRate, VideoCodec.FLV1, 5242880)
            'For cPosicion = 0 To cTamaño - 1
            '    cImagen = cVideo(cPosicion)
            '    Dim vbmp As Bitmap
            '    vbmp = New Bitmap(cImagen, CInt(AnchoTxt.Text), CInt(AltoTxt.Text))
            '    cGrabacion.WriteVideoFrame(vbmp)
            '    GC.Collect()
            'Next
            'cGrabacion.Close()
        Next
    End If
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el constructor.

```
Public Sub VideoWriter()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim compressionCode As Integer
    Dim fps As Integer
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim isColor As Boolean
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te está indicando el error es que no se puede crear el objeto `VideoWriter` porque no se encuentra un constructor sin argumentos.

La clase `VideoWriter` de la librería Emgu CV tiene 3 constructores, ninguno de ellos sin argumentos. Uno de ellos además está marcado como obsoleto con lo que deberías utilizar uno de los otros dos:

```
public VideoWriter(
    string fileName,
    int fps,
    int width,
    int height,
    bool isColor
)

Parameters
fileName (String)
The name of the video file to be written to
fps (Int32)
frame rate per second
width (Int32)
the width of the frame
height (Int32)
the height of the frame
isColor (Boolean)
true if this is a color video, false otherwise


public VideoWriter(
    string fileName,
    int compressionCode,
    int fps,
    int width,
    int height,
    bool isColor
)

Parameters
fileName (String)
The name of the video file to be written to
compressionCode (Int32)
compression code
fps (Int32)
frame rate per second
width (Int32)
the width of the frame
height (Int32)
the height of the frame
isColor (Boolean)
true if this is a color video, false otherwise
```

[VideoWriter Class](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/3fb90645-ecc4-0c4e-b238-6d0ca38f4ebc.htm)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, es que tengo que cambiar un proyecto que usaba una liberia aforge, a emgu.cv. Entiendo que le tengo que pasar esos valores al metodo VideoWriter no?

Comment: Sí claro, para crear una instancia de la clase VideoWriter debes llamar a uno de los dos constructores utilizando New: `cGrabacion = New VideoWriter(fileName, fps, width, height, isColor)`

Comment: Okey, y luego al hacer el cGrabacion.open() ahi le paso todas las variables con los datos no? sry, es que es la primera vez que toco vb.net y ando bastante pillado

Comment: Por cierto, me acabo de encontrar con un error, al el metodo con las variables, fileName, fps y isColor, me dice que no esta declarado, o puede que no sea accesible por el nivel de seguridad

Comment: Edito la pregunta, con la imagen del fallo del constructor.

Comment: tambien me dice, que no encuentras las variables del constructor...